# How can I create a new gesture keyboard

Tags: android, gesture, android-softkeyboard

I wanted to create an new gesture keyboard which can be used by all other application.
i followed these links 
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/creating-input-method.html 
and
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SoftKeyboard/index.html

and tried out the sample but there is nothing happened! 
Can any one help me on this???
thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I realized the error
i tried out this example at http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SoftKeyboard/index.html
and problem was i need to update my api to 14 since some methods are needed api 14 to compile and also i have to set(checked or activate) my keyboard under settings-> "language and keyboard"